# Hot to make gradient half red / half blue?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Currently the whole thing is red.

How would I make this gradient, half the left side red, half blue?

That is all I am trying to do in the code.

[image]

```css
div {
   width: 640px;
   height: 340px;
   background:
     linear-gradient(45deg,
       transparent,
       transparent 7px,
       red 7px,
       red 7.5px,
       transparent 7.5px,
       transparent 10px),
     linear-gradient(-45deg,
       transparent,
       transparent 7px,
       red 7px,
       red 7.5px,
       transparent 7.5px,
       transparent 10px);
   background-size: 10px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I am not quite clear. Do. You want the left half or the whole div to be say red and the right half of the whole div to be say blue, or are talking about each of those small, mesh-like areas?

Comment: The lines instead of the background. The lines are what should be different colors, not the background area. In my updated code, the lines I have as red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your gradient configuration inside mask then consider a regular background for your separation. I optimized you gradient configuration a little as well:

```css
div {
  width: 640px;
  height: 340px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%,blue 0);
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient( 45deg, #0000 7px, #000 0 7.5px, #0000 0 10px), 
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #0000 7px, #000 0 7.5px, #0000 0 10px);
  -webkit-mask-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of half of the block we place the layer in a pseudo-element with a css filter on the background. Filter properties are different. In our case, we apply a filter that rotates the hue palette `backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(240deg)` so that the red becomes blue. `240deg` means rotate 240 degrees clockwise.

[image]

```css
div {
  width: 640px;
  height: 340px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, red 7px, red 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, red 7px, red 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(240deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Good answers provide some explanation of the code.

Comment: @Sean its a magic. 

Answer (score 0):

You could use `repeating-linear-gradient`, `background-size`, `background-position` , `background-repeat` and `background-position` all together. So you can lay on different areas differents sized gradients

Possible example:

```css
div {
  border:solid;
   width: 640px;
   aspect-ratio:3/1.5;
   background:
     repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg,transparent 0 7px,red  7px 8px,transparent 8px  10px) 0 0       / 50% 100% no-repeat,
     repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,transparent 0 7px,red  7px 8px,transparent 8px  10px) 0 0       / 50% 100% no-repeat,
     repeating-linear-gradient(225deg,transparent 0 7px,blue 7px 8px,transparent 8px  10px) 100% 0   / 50% 100% no-repeat,
     repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,transparent 0 7px,blue 7px 8px,transparent 8px  10px) 100% 0px / 50% 100% no-repeat
     ivory /* bgcolor */
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The grid has a ‘break’ as it goes from red to blue, at least on the iPad I’m currently confined to. (Not sure whether that’s a problem for the OP or not of course).